# How to get rid of console warning "enableRowSelect has been deprecated... Please use rowSelection instead.""

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-data-grid

)
I'm using React Data Grid(https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/) a few times in my app. I've noticed that there is a console warning for a prop "enableRowSelect", that prints whether you are using the aforementioned prop or not.

Console Warning:

> enableRowSelect has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use rowSelection instead

minimal, reproducible example
Install RDG
$ `npm install react-data-grid --save`
or with yarn:
$ `yarn add react-data-grid`

*file.tsx*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid';

const columns = [
  { key: 'id', name: 'ID' },
  { key: 'title', name: 'Title' },
  { key: 'count', name: 'Count' } ];

const rows = [{id: 0, title: 'row1', count: 20}, {id: 1, title: 'row1', count: 40}, {id: 2, title: 'row1', count: 60}];

function HelloWorld() {
  return (
    <ReactDataGrid
      columns={columns}
      rowGetter={i => rows[i]}
      rowsCount={3}
    />
  );
}
```

check your console

That's actually snippet from: 
https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/examples/simple-grid

You can check your console warnings @ that linked page as well.

I expect that when I'm using the base grid as described in the docs, that there will be no errors/warnings.

```
     ?                                0     1     1
 ><({,''>                         <'',}})><   1   0          
                                   0   1  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Workaround:
Set prop 'enableRowSelect' to null :

```
<ReactDataGrid
  columns={this.state.columns}
  rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
  rowsCount={this.getSize()}

  enableRowSelect={null}

  />
```

Edit: It appears that it will be fixed in the `7.0.0` release. The fix is included in `7.0.0-alpha.18`. More details [here](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/1403#issuecomment-529417574)